# Contingency table plus confidence intervals

Tags: r, plyr, contingency, deducer

I've recently discovered deducer and it's contingency table function (see [Exporting deducer's contingency tables as csv or xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577892/exporting-deducers-contingency-tables-as-csv-or-xls))

What I'm trying to do is plot the values from a contingency table in ggplot to show a barplot with % frequency up the y-axis and categorical data along the x-axis. Then if possible I'd like to produce error bars to show the confidence interval for the proportion of each variable from the whole.

For examples using the `mtcars` data, R produces this using the `contingency.tables` function:

```
    table_gears<-contingency.tables(
    row.vars=d(cyl),
    col.vars=d(gear),data=mtcars)
print(table_gears,prop.r=T,prop.c=T,prop.t=F)
```

Basically the proportion of cars with x gears and y cylinders calculated over both row totals and column totals.

Does anyone no of a way of producing this using ddply or similar and adding in the standards error/confidence interval of these proportions too? I am really struggling and would be really grateful for a lifeline!

Comment: Have you tried the ggplot2 documentation? http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html and http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_errorbar.html give you a barplot and the confidence intervals.

Comment: i have read this documentation, but I need to summarise my data first, as I'd quite like to have summary data tables showing the counts, and proportions and because as far as I can tell geom_errorbar won't calculate the frequency of proportions. cheers

Comment: Link now broken, a good reason to have answers on-site.